# How should an OSD be coded with PyGI?

Tags: development, pygi

How is an OSD meant to be coded, using pygobject? Is it just an undecorated window that is application-paintable? Please provide all the details that you can (e.g. whether one has to use cairo, connect to the draw signal, ...)

Comment: Could you describe what you are trying to create in a little more detail? 'On-screen display' isn't much to go on, and PyGI is a pretty broad category of tools as well. (That's pretty well Python + any library that uses GObject).

Comment: I'm trying to create a sort of weather indicator applet. Through the indicator menu the user should be able to open an OSD that will show more detailed weather forecasts. The idea is to have something similar to the Notify-OSD (same look-and-feel but with arbitrary widget contents).

Comment: @Phoenix87 Is this 5 year old project, which would have been built using Ubuntu 12.04 (now EOL), still an on-going concern? It would be nice to have it answered or deleted from the `unanswered questions` list. Thank you.